# I want to add create bar with add button in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and kind of confuse why it's not working
I making list website where you add something on list and it updates shows the new added element on the same page. I am almost done the only thing left is creating new element where i am facing problem. Thank you

models.py:-

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.


class simpleList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import simpleList
from django.views.generic import ListView, DeleteView, CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
# Create your views here.


class ListListView(ListView):
    model = simpleList
    template_name = 'list_list.html'


class DeleteList(SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    model = simpleList
    success_url = reverse_lazy('list_list')
    success_message = "deleted..."

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        title = self.object.title
        request.session['title'] = title
        return super(DeleteView, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)


class CreateList(CreateView):
    model = simpleList
    template_name = 'list_list.html'
```

urls.py:-

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ListListView, DeleteList, CreateList
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', ListListView.as_view(), name='list_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', DeleteList.as_view(), name='delete_view'),
    path('new/', CreateList.as_view(), name='create_list'),
]
```

list_list.html:-

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}sList{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<h2>simpleList</h2>
<form action="{% url 'create_list' pk=simpleList.pk %}" method=" POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">S.No</th>
            <th scope="col">Task</th>
            <th scope="col">Done</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<div>
    {% for simpleList in object_list %}
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead style="display: none;">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">S.No</th>
                <th scope="col">Task</th>
                <th scope="col">Done</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <div>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="table-primary">
                    <th scope="row">{{ simpleList.pk }}</th>
                    <td style="max-width: 100px;  word-break: break-all;">
                        {{ simpleList.title }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'delete_view' pk=simpleList.pk %}">{% csrf_token %}
                            <input class="btn btn-default btn-danger" type="submit" value="Done" />
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </div>
    </table>
</div>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

The error i am receiving is this:-

```
Reverse for 'create_list' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['list/new/$']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `Reverse for 'create_list' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found.` indicates that somewhere you're trying to create a link to the `create_list` view with incorrect arguments.

In your `urls.py` file, you don't have any argument for the `create_list` view (`path('new/', CreateList.as_view(), name='create_list'),`). However, in your list_list.html, you're trying to create a link to this view with a `pk` argument in the action attribute of your form:
`{% url 'create_list' pk=simpleList.pk %}`

Try to add the `pk` argument in `urls.py` or remove it from the link in the action attribute of your form.

Comment: thank you sir it's working but now when i add something it does not store in data base or anywhere else its just refreshes. Can you help with this as well. Thank you

Comment: You're not handling the validation of the form properly. I suggest you have a look at the [Form handling with class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) page of the Django documentation. Especially, you should create a `forms.py` file with a class dedicated to your form.